# Validating sitemaps with images tag

Tags: sitemap, validation

I am trying to add the `<image>` tag to my sitemap, but even trying to look at the XSD , as mentioned by Google at  http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=183668 , I get 404 Error not found (the XSD link: http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1 ). How is that possible? Is there anyway I can validate it without the XSD?

Answer (score 4):

You can find your answer in the same link you passed (http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=183668), in the section Sitemap Extensions.

Comment: Sorry Dave, just saw your answer. I read the mentioned section, but maybe I am not getting something... As I wrote, I did include the images name space as required. The problem with the URL given by the documentation (http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1) is that it does not exist (page not found). Maybe I am missing something with the way I should validate my XML with that name schema?

Comment: @Joel, yeah, I think you didn't pay the attention to that section. Note that header example has xmlns:image="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" link, but in the Sitemap Extensions section, they inform: xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1". As you can see, the correct namespace is within google domain, not sitemap.

Comment: thanks Dave! I missed that one :/ Weird why at the beginning of the page they have the sitemaps.org site in the tag and later on they change to Google ...

Comment: @Joel: yeap, really strange indeed, but we know those things can happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for schema validation, you need to also reference the proper XSD files:

<urlset  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation=
        "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd
        http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1 http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1/sitemap-image.xsd"
         xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
         xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">